# Textures using AMD Orochi?

Tags: textures, amd-processor, hip

I'm using the [HIPRT](https://gpuopen.com/hiprt/) and [Orochi](https://gpuopen.com/orochi/) libraries to write a path tracer and I'd like to be able to handle texutres. However, the [tutorials](https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/HIPRTSDK/tree/main/tutorials) don't give examples on how to use textures with Orochi and the main Orochi header [suggests](https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/Orochi/blob/main/Orochi/Orochi.h#L717) that textures aren't implemented yet.

Am I going to have to use "pure" HIP (meaning that I will need two executables: one for NVIDIA and one for AMD hardware despite the selling point of Orochi being that you can choose between NVIDIA and AMD at runtime) on top of Orochi to be able to use textures or did I miss something?